# get_posts() not working with multiple statuses

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I am running the following code:

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type'   => ['my-type', 'another-type'],
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'orderby'     => 'title',
    'post_status' => ['published','future']
]);
```

It is only returning the status that appears last in the array.  So in the above example it returns all posts with status `future`.  If I swapped the order it would return only the `published` posts.

I set a break point and get the args being passed to WP_Query() and here they are:

```
Array
(
    [numberposts] => -1
    [category] => 0
    [orderby] => title
    [order] => ASC
    [include] => Array
        (
        )

    [exclude] => Array
        (
        )

    [meta_key] => 
    [meta_value] => 
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => my-type
            [1] => another-type
        )

    [suppress_filters] => 1
    [post_status] => Array
        (
            [0] => published
            [1] => future
        )

    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 1
    [no_found_rows] => 1
)
```

I have seen examples where the status and type is passed as an array.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct post status for published posts is `publish`. Post statuses are in present tense (So `publish`, not `published`, and `draft`, not `drafted`).